# R "prob" package doesn't install - failing dependencies

Tags: r

- R version 3.4.2,
- RStudio 1.1.383,
- Windows 10

CRAN removed the "prob" package for R, which several open source probability textbooks depend upon.

- What I did to solve this:

Another user suggested R 2.9. However,

- R 2.9 breaks Rstudio,
- prob isn't actually in the CRAN repository for 2.9, and
- none of the versions of fAsianOptions available in the archive
  install for it, anyway. (Already tried all of these.)

Investigating several topic areas in Rdocumentation turned up nothing. This used to be a popular package and other works were written that depend upon it. Now that it is broken/gone, what is the workaround?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: It is not a matter of opinion. It's a matter of how to install an R package necessary for working with probabilities that was removed less than a month ago. The earlier solution someone provided here (use R 2.9) failed in the two ways I already described. Now, I'm looking for additional suggestions as others are surely going through this as well. Especially as there doesn't seem to be anything else like prob available in rdocumentation.org, too.

Comment: You can still download it from [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/). On the left click `Packages` and near the bottom of the page `Archive`. It's still there.

Comment: As mentioned by another person, you might still be able to download the package. But I'll give the general advice that you'll probably reach more people who are qualified to answer this question on the r-help mailing list. See: https://www.r-project.org/mail.html

Comment: As mentioned above, it depends upon fAsianOptions, which does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Install dependencies first.

```
install.packages("installr")  # Not appropriate for Macs
library(installr)
install.Rtools()
```

Download the latest  fAsianOptions...tar.gz from the Archives

Dependencies are listed in the `../prob/DESCRIPTION` file (which has no extension but is a simple text file). If these are all installed then:

```
install.packages("~/Downloads/fAsianOptions", repo=NULL,type="source")
```

That does need compilation so you needed to have the proper development tools for Windows. Note that it, too, has dependencies, so install them as well:

```
 # In the DESCRIPTION file for fAsianOptions you read ->
 #  Depends: R (>= 2.4.0), timeDate, timeSeries, fBasics, fOptions

 # If you had not installed all the dependnecies you would need:

 install.packages("~/Downloads/fAsianOptions", dependencies=TRUE, 
                  repo=NULL, type="source")
```

The combinat package can be installed from CRAN:

```
install.packages("combinat")
```

Then when your dependencies are satisfied (and you know where your `../prob`-directory is in your filesystem):

```
install.packages("~/Downloads/prob", repo=NULL,type="source")
# obviously something else should be substituted for `~/Downloads/`
```

Comment: All of these are already installed:

Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘fAsianOptions_3010.79.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

Comment: What version of RTools do you have? And do post complete error messages.

Comment: RTools version 3.4
install.packages("fAsianOptions_3010.tar.gz", dependencies=TRUE, repos=NULL, type = "source")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Tlk7/Documents/R/win-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning: invalid package 'fAsianOptions_3010.tar.gz'
Error: ERROR: no packages specified
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.2/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\Tlk7\Documents\R\win-library\3.4" "fAsianOptions_3010.tar.gz"' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘fAsianOptions_3010.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

Comment: In what directory is the tar.gz file located? Have you expanded it? (I did.) You might get OS-specific information with `?INSTALL`

Comment: It is in a directory called Packages in a different, non-R directory.
Yes, I expanded it and tried it. I have also tried it non-expanded. I get exactly the same message as above, both ways.

Comment: Got it to work! Thanks for your help. Am posting the solution below.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution, thanks to 42- above.

So, for others who might encounter this same situation:

1. Install RTools from here: https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/Rtools34.exe 
   Trying to install Rtools from inside RStudio will result in an "it's not available for 3.4.2"  message.
2. Install the following dependencies: timeDate, timeSeries, fBasics, fOptions
3. Download fAsianOptions from here: https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/fAsianOptions/fAsianOptions_3010.79.tar.gz
   and prob from here: https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/prob/prob_1.0-0.tar.gz
4. Unzip each into its own directory.
5. Use this to install each, as appropriate: install.packages("~/Downloads/fAsianOptions", dependencies=TRUE, repos=NULL, type = "source")